# How do I construct an SQL query that matches a varchar column with several values (MS Access .mdb)?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm producing a database system, and need to run a query where my VARCHAR column needs to match any one of several values. For example;

```sql
SELECT * FROM CompressedTags
WHERE TagValue ISEITHER("FOO","BAR","OTHER")
```

I'm aware that I could write this as;

```sql
SELECT * FROM CompressedTags
WHERE TagValue="FOO" OR TagValue="BAR" OR TagValue="OTHER"
```

I'm just wondering if there's a nice, tidier alternative like the "ISEITHER" function that I posted above? Note that I'm using a MS-Access database, and I'd prefer to use an `OleDbCommand` to accomplish this if possible!

Comment: [The IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: you could have figured this out very easily by using `Google`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `IN` with the list of your target values ...

```sql
WHERE TagValue IN ('FOO', 'BAR', 'OTHER')
```

So that `WHERE` condition will be satisfied for any rows whose `TagValue` matches any of those 3 strings.

Comment: Much appreciated; I saw an example of "IN" being used with another database, but I didn't realise I could use it for lists! :-)

Comment: `IN` can also be used with a subquery: `WHERE TagValue IN (SELECT sample_values FROM another_table)` ... in that case the match targets are retrieved at runtime from the other data source, instead of being listed as a hard-coded list of values in the SQL statement such as `IN ('FOO', 'BAR', 'OTHER')`

Comment: Apologies for my lack of knowledge of SQL, but is there an equivalent operator but for LIKE, so I could type "WHERE TagValue LIKEANY ('%FOO%', '%BAR%', '%OTHER%')"?

Comment: Not in Access SQL that I know about.  I think you would have to do `TagValue Like '%FOO%' OR TagValue Like '%BAR%'` ... etc.